# Browser handling of REALLY massive images

Tags: css, image, memory, browser

Does anyone have any experience/information on how browsers handle really big images. We're using a series of large jpeg's to imitate video (don't ask why) and are wondering if there are any problems with combining them all into one large jpeg and using background positioning to advance the frames. If our images were small then this approach would probably be worth the effort due to fewer http requests and greater jpeg compression, but as the images are large (about 30kb each) and numerous (700 frames) it'd be good to knwo if there are any known issues with throwing such large images at a browsers.

Comment: If it's a single image, the browser would have to store it as a bitmap in memory. 320x240x3x700 ~ 150 MB for just the image.

Answer (score 0):

30Kb is not that large, but you may have problems with outputting the amount of images you want to a browser if the images are on a remote server because the images may not refresh quickly enough.

Comment: This is our current approach (using separate images) and yes, it was very difficult getting the images to refresh quickly enough across all browsers (big memory leaks in mozilla)... but I think you misunderstood the question as I want to combine 700 (or maybe 7 sets of 100) 30kb images into larger ones

Answer (score 0):

[JPEG has a maximum image size of 65535x65535](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#cite_note-2) so you may have to arrange your frames in a square rather than a simple film strip, and you may still run out of space.